# Extract dataframe column values as standalone columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe defined as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['US', 'US', 'CA', 'CA', 'BE', 'BE', 'BE', 'MX'], 
                   'Language': ['en', 'es', 'en', 'fr', 'nl', 'fr', 'de', 'es']})
```

[image]

I'd like to pivot/transform this dataframe such that the values under language column make separate columns, like

[image]

What is the cleanest and most panda-ic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assign a new column and do a pivot based on that column:

```
df.assign(
    lang_id='Lang' + df.groupby('Country').cumcount().add(1).astype('str')
    ).pivot(index='Country', columns='lang_id', values='Language').reset_index()

lang_id Country Lang1 Lang2 Lang3
0            BE    nl    fr    de
1            CA    en    fr  None
2            MX    es  None  None
3            US    en    es  None
```

Another alternative would be:

```
df.groupby('Country')['Language'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).reset_index()
Out: 
  Country   0    1    2
0      BE  nl   fr   de
1      CA  en   fr  NaN
2      MX  es  NaN  NaN
3      US  en   es  NaN
```

For both, you can call `fillna('')` at the end to fill the NaNs with empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['US', 'US', 'CA', 'CA', 'BE', 'BE', 'BE', 'MX'], 
               'Language': ['en', 'es', 'en', 'fr', 'nl', 'fr', 'de', 'es']})
```

First find unique languages for each country with `groupby` and `unique()`.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["Country"])["Language"].unique().reset_index())

# df2
#   Country     Language
# 0     BE     [nl, fr, de]
# 1     CA     [en, fr]
# 2     MX     [es]
# 3     US     [en, es]

# Then split Language column into 3 columns
langs = df2.Language.values.tolist()).add_prefix('Lang')

# concat two df to get the desired output
pd.concat([df2.Country, langs], axis=1)

      Country  Lang0    Lang1   Lang2
  0     BE      nl      fr      de
  1     CA      en      fr      None
  2     MX      es      None    None
  3     US      en      es      None
```